# How to comment a line in a Makefile?

Tags: variables, makefile, comments

Within a makefile I have a some variables. For a better understanding I added some comments:

```
variable1 = value1     #A comment
variable2 = true       #can be set true or false
variable3 = foo        #can be foo or bar
```

The problem is now, that the variables contain the given text **and** all spaces between the text and the `#`. The output of a simple echo shows the problem:

```
echo "$(variable1) $(variable2) endOfEcho"
value1      true       endOfEcho
```

How to avoid the spaces to be interpreted as variable's text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU make:

```
@echo "$(strip $(variable1)) $(strip $(variable2)) endOfEcho"
value1 true endOfEcho

@echo "$(variable1) $(variable2) endOfEcho"
value1      true        endOfEcho

@echo $(variable1) $(variable2) endOfEcho
value1 true endOfEcho
```