# makefile miss separator but it is not the tab problem

Tags: c, makefile

both of these two makefiles give me the message of

```
[Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop]
```

I am sure I used the tab.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Post text as text, not pictures of text, and *not* links to pictures of text.

Comment: Don't post links to screen shots, post the code!  Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: [What is the comment character in Linux Makefile](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+the+comment+character+in+Linux+Makefile), [How to comment a line in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40928674/608639), [How do I properly comment a variable definition in GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31586713/608639), [How to add multi line comments in makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4493291/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

`//` is not a comment delimeter in make, so the error is complaining about the first line -- it begins with a name (`//`) that is not followed by a colon (so its not a rule) or `=` (so its not a variable assignment).

Use `#` for comments in a Makefile